# Unsubscribed workshop mods still taking up space

Tags: steam, steam-workshop

I've unsubscribed from all of my Arma 3 workshop mods - however they're still taking up space on my computer, and I'm unsure as to how I'd physically get rid of them.

image from before deleting

[image: image from before deleting]

image from after deleting

[image: image from after deleting.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - I had to uninstall the game, and all of the installed mods went with it.

[image: cleaned folder]